# Who decides upon the title for blog posts?

Tags: discussion, blog

Who decides upon the title of blog posts on the Stack Overflow blog, such as [Tapping into the coding power of migrants and refugees in Mexico](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/08/tapping-into-the-coding-power-of-migrants-and-refugees-in-mexico/?cb=1)? Is it the author of the blog post, Stack Exchange, Inc., or a little bit of both?

I'm asking because I've heard that with newspapers, the titles of articles and opinion pieces aren't chosen by the author of them, but by the editors. If that were true, then posting a comment in the blog piece about something the blog author isn't responsible for wouldn't be fair to the author.

Comment: Based on reading some guess blog posts on SE, I have a feeling that the author has almost full control of the content and the editors only do copyedit, though it's also questionable since I have seen few occurrences of typo on "Stack Overflow" (e.g. without space)

Comment: That blog post is also embarrassingly full of missing words, spelling, and grammar errors. Why don't some staff member read it through before publication? It is, after all, the official blog of Stack Exchange (about [100 million USD revenue per year](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfxd9y0cMY&t=15m57s)). No matter the original author, it falls back on Stack Exchange the company.

Comment: @Peter I usually notice spelling and grammar errors even if I don’t want to, and yet I didn’t notice anything while reading it. I read a few paragraphs of it again. I see a few phrases joined together in sentences, as if it were spoken English rather than written, but apart from that I didn’t notice anything.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I just fed the blog post into Pages to check for spelling errors. The only red squiggles I got were for American English, "Holacode" (and related words, and "fullstack". And yet you say that it's embarrassingly full of spelling errors?

Comment: @Andrew maybe Peter refers to the humor/fun parts, e.g. "We have something fun for ya", or "surfing a perfect wave like pros"?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm The post was tacitly changed after publication. It was indeed full of all kinds of errors when I first saw it, but now they seem to be fixed.

Comment: @Emil it was quite a while from when it was first published to when I first read it, so I probably never saw the original version.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Authors can suggest titles. Final titles are set by the members of the Stack Overflow Marketing department who work on editing blog posts and curating content.

Comment: So the blog authors can only save drafts, and only SOM member can publish? Or do they have some dialog before posting the blog? :)

Comment: There is definitely dialog. SOM will fix small issues (spelling, grammar, typos, etc) on their own, but if more substantive edits are needed it is always done on coordination with the actual author. As far as publishing, this is always done by SOM, as publishing is done on a schedule that they control.

Comment: Lately the titles are always wrong (having weird [OBJ] characters) and content itself usually have glaring issues too. Guess something changed in the Stack Overflow Marketing department? After those bugs are reported here someone fix it, usually, but still, it doesn't look good, to say the least, and not what one would expect from a professional company like Stack Exchange.